# Ruby - File.rename() Permission Denied

Tags: ruby

On Ruby Im trying to fill a temporary file then rename it but getting permission errors on Windows.

```
File.rename("tempFile.csv", @data_file)
```

Error

```
 Permission denied - tempFile.csv (Errno::EACCES)
```

Comment: Is `tempFile.csv` still open?

Comment: closing has no effect it seems. f.close? It still gives permission error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to place

```
File.chmod(0755, "tempFile.csv") rescue nil
```

before

```
File.rename("tempFile.csv", @data_file)
```